# Why doesn’t my StreamBuilder change the displayed page as soon as data is available in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I am currently programming an app in which the following should be possible:

1. A list of selectable levels should be displayed to the user.

[image]

That works.

This is the code section that creates the list:

```
Map<String, bool> levels = {
    'Level 1': false,
    'Level 2': false,
    'Level 3': false,
    'Level 4': false,
    'Level 5': false,
    'Level 6': false
  };

  void toggleDone(String key) {
    setState(() {
      levels.update(key, (bool value) => !value);
    });
  }

//Here’s actually more code, I’ll show it later, since it’s not important for this part.

ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            );
                          },
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          itemCount: levels.length,
                          itemBuilder: (buildContext, i) {
                            String key = levels.keys.elementAt(i);
                            return LevelItem(
                              key,
                              levels[key]!,
                                  () => toggleDone(key),
                                  () => select(key),
                            );
                          }); //This is the list with the levels.

//Here’s actually more code, I’ll show it later, since it’s not important for this part.

class LevelItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String level;
  final bool value;
  final Function toggleDone;
  final Function select;
  const LevelItem(this.level, this.value, this.toggleDone, this.select);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile(
        value: value,
        title: Text(level),
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          toggleDone();
          if (value == true) select();
        });
  }
} //That’s the ListTile you can pick. (You'll see later, what "select does...
```

2. When the user selects a level, certain To-Dos should be stored in Cloud Firestore.

[image]

That works too!

I can reach this via the above mentioned “select () “ function:

```
void select(key) {
    if (key == 'Level 1') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 2') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 3') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 4') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
      database.setTodo('Fettsäureverhältnis', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 5') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
      database.setTodo('Fettsäureverhältnis', false);
      database.setTodo('Nährstoffbedarf', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 6') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
      database.setTodo('Fettsäureverhältnis', false);
      database.setTodo('Nährstoffbedarf', false);
      database.setTodo('Kohlenhydrate', false);
    }
  }
```

> database.setTodo(...); calls the following function:

```
final CollectionReference userTodos =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');

  Future setTodo(String item, bool value) async {
    return await userTodos
        .doc(userID)
        .set({item: value}, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
```

3.)A StreamBuilder should display the view with steps, as long as no data (To-Dos) is stored in Cloud Firestore. If this changes, the StreamBuilder should show the data (To-Dos).

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: database.getTodos(),
                    builder:
                        (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> level = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              );
                            },
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            itemCount: level.length,
                            itemBuilder: (buildContext, i) {
                              String key = level.keys.elementAt(i);
                              return ToDoItem(
                                key,
                                level[key]!,
                                    () => toggleDone(key),
                              );
                            });
                      }
                       return ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            );
                          },
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          itemCount: levels.length,
                          itemBuilder: (buildContext, i) {
                            String key = levels.keys.elementAt(i);
                            return LevelItem(
                              key,
                              levels[key]!,
                                  () => toggleDone(key),
                                  () => select(key),
                            );
                          });
                    },
                  );
```

---

Right now, point one and two work, but point three doesn’t work. The StreamBuilder does not change from the ListView to the to-dos, which are stored in Cloud Firestore.

So that’s the full code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  User? user;
  late DatabaseService database;

  Future<void> standard() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    user = _auth.currentUser;
    database = DatabaseService(user!.uid);
  }

  Map<String, bool> levels = {
    'Level 1': false,
    'Level 2': false,
    'Level 3': false,
    'Level 4': false,
    'Level 5': false,
    'Level 6': false
  };

  void toggleDone(String key) {
    setState(() {
      levels.update(key, (bool value) => !value);
    });
  }

  void select(key) {
    if (key == 'Level 1') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 2') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 3') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 4') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
      database.setTodo('Fettsäureverhältnis', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 5') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
      database.setTodo('Fettsäureverhältnis', false);
      database.setTodo('Nährstoffbedarf', false);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 6') {
      database.setTodo('Milchprodukte', false);
      database.setTodo('Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke', false);
      database.setTodo('glykämische Last', false);
      database.setTodo('Fettsäureverhältnis', false);
      database.setTodo('Nährstoffbedarf', false);
      database.setTodo('Kohlenhydrate', false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 112, 192, 1),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
              future: standard(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else {
                  return StreamBuilder(
                    stream: database.getTodos(),
                    builder:
                        (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> level = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              );
                            },
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            itemCount: level.length,
                            itemBuilder: (buildContext, i) {
                              String key = level.keys.elementAt(i);
                              return ToDoItem(
                                key,
                                level[key]!,
                                    () => toggleDone(key),
                              );
                            });
                      }
                       return ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            );
                          },
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          itemCount: levels.length,
                          itemBuilder: (buildContext, i) {
                            String key = levels.keys.elementAt(i);
                            return LevelItem(
                              key,
                              levels[key]!,
                                  () => toggleDone(key),
                                  () => select(key),
                            );
                          });
                    },
                  );
                }
              }));
    }
  }

class LevelItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String level;
  final bool value;
  final Function toggleDone;
  final Function select;
  const LevelItem(this.level, this.value, this.toggleDone, this.select);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile(
        value: value,
        title: Text(level),
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          toggleDone();
          if (value == true) select();
        });
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help! If certain information is missing, just write me and I will send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is that you don't need to wrap your StreamBuilder in a FutureBuilder and that this may be the source of your issue. The AsyncSnapshot provided by the StreamBuilder's builder has several properties that should cover all the cases you are trying to account for. Also, StreamBuilder itself has many handy features, like: setting initial data and several helpful callbacks. But by wrapping your StreamBuilder in a FutureBuilder you may have set a requirement to not rebuild until a new Future is returned.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

But, if you know for a fact that your StreamBuilder is the problem and that it is not rebuilding when you think it should, I would check that the stream obtained from `getTodos()` is actually receiving events.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! I've changed the code. Now I don't use the FutureBuilder, but the screen still doesn't switch. I added ´print(snapshot);´ infront of the ListView that gets displayed. Here is what gets printet: `I/flutter (16911): AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(ConnectionState.active, Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot', null, null)`  Does this mean the snapshot has no data?

Comment: Now I've put the snapshot into an map: `Map<String, dynamic> level =
            snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print(level);`  After runnning my app it prints this: `I/flutter (19049): {Süßigkeiten & süße Getränke: false, Milchprodukte: false, Nährstoffbedarf: false, glykämische Last: false, Fettsäureverhältnis: false}`

Comment: That is exacly what I want the snapshot to return, but at the same time I'm getting an error, because the null check ist used on a null value: `Map<String, dynamic> level =
            snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;`  Now I'm confused! `print(snapshot);` shows me, that the Stream works, but at the same time it says `snapshot.data!.data` ist null?!

Comment: OK, 1) You are checking if snapshot hasData but you aren't returning within that scope and so it always continues to the following scope.
2) the 'data' member of AsyncSnapshot has the type T? and you can set that by adding a type <> param to your StreamBuilder. So when your snapshot hasData, data is a Map, judging by your comments here. Although, without explicitly declaring it might be seen as a generic Object until runtime. So calling data.data() isn't going to work unless the type you are passing has a member function 'data()'.

Comment: In other words, 'data' just is whatever type your stream spits out.

Comment: Thank you, I just hat to add `return` before `ListView...`.